# Expectation, concave function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $E[X]<+\infty$, and $Y$ be a random variable independent of $X$ such that $E[Y]=0$.
Define $Z=X+Y$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a concave function.

Show that $E[g(X)]\geq E[g(Z)]$.

I don't see how to use the concavity of $g$ since $Z$ is not a convex combination of $X$ and $Y$. I don't think Jensen's inequality can be used here...

Answer (score 3):

You may require the conditional expectation version of jensen's inequality

$$E[g(Z)]=E[g(X+Y)]= E[E[g(X+Y)|X]] \leq E[g(E[X+Y|X])]$$
$$= E[g(X+E[Y|X])] = E[g(X)]$$
where we used that $E[Y|X]=E[Y]=0$ as $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, just to fix ideas, that both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous r.v.s that admit *pdf*. Suppose $g$ is concave. Then $$\mathbb{E}[g(X+Y)]=\int\int g(x+y)f_{Y}(y)f_{X}(x)dydx\leq\int g\left(\int(x+y)f_{Y}(y)dy\right)f_{X}(x)dx=\int g(x)f_{X}(x)dx=\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$$ where the inequality follows by Jensen's inequality.

As a side remark, in economics (choice under uncertainty), $Y$ is called mean-preserving spread of $X$. One can define '$X$ second-order stochastically dominates $Y$' if expected utility of risk averse decision maker is weakly higher under $X$ than under $Y$. Then '$X$ is mean-preserving spread of $Y$' and '$X$ second-order stochastically dominates $Y$ are equivalent'. See Section 6.D in [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microeconomic-Theory-Whinston-J-R-Green-Mas-Colell/dp/B003RHHUA6/ref=sr_1_2/255-7884357-4014461?ie=UTF8&qid=1486387586&sr=8-2&keywords=mas+colell+whinston).

Comment: If you recall economy, I propose to check whether Ohlin's Lemma is applicable. Originally it was proved in 1969 in a statistical journal. For a statement look here: http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~schmidli/vorl/Risk/concave.pdf It is also possible to get the original Ohlin's paper in the Internet.

Comment: Let me add to @szw1710. As far as I know the lemma says that given two r.v.s $X$ and $Y$ with the same mean and one switch in $F_{X}-F_{Y}$ from $-$ to $+$, $\mathbb{E}[u(X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(Y)$ for any convex $u$. This is the original paper: http://www.actuaries.org/LIBRARY/ASTIN/vol5no2/249.pdf